# Find the most frequently occurring value in Parse database

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, mongodb, parse-platform

I see no documentation on how to find the most frequently occurring value in a table in Parse. How can I make this query (iOS answers preferred, but not limited to)

I'm thinking that I can use some kind of compound query with an NSPredicate, but I'm still very unsure as to how to go about this calculation.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of Parse to know if there's a good way to do this in a query, but If you can retrieve all the values, you can put them in to an NSCountedSet, and query that for the item with the largest count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could helps you :

```
NSArray *yourarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];
NSCountedSet *yourset = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:yourarray];

for (id item in yourset) {
    NSLog(@"Count of %@ is %lu", item, (unsigned long)[yourset countForObject:item]);
}
```

This could be the NSPredicate example (didn't try, cause I wrote in TextMate) :

```
NSDictionary *dic1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:99] forKey:@"visitCount"];
NSDictionary *dic2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"visitCount"];
NSDictionary *dic3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1003] forKey:@"visitCount"];
NSDictionary *dic4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1005] forKey:@"visitCount"];
NSDictionary *dic5 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:107] forKey:@"visitCount"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4, dic5, nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.visitCount == %@.@max.visitCount", array];

NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Max in objects: %@", result);
```

Comment: is there any way to turn this into an nspredicate?